# How to get users i have had conversation with in laravel without a conversation table and participant table

Tags: php, laravel

Please i have two tables, Users table and Message tables below

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('from');
$table->unsignedInteger('to');
$table->mediumText('text');
$table->boolean('read')->default(false);
```

and these two relationship in User Class

```
public function sentMessages(){
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'from');
}
public function receivedMessages(){
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'to');
}
```

I want to get only user i have conversation with.. How can i do that.. even with raw sql

Answer (score 0):

If you just what the users you can do:

```
 $userId = 'id of user to get conversations for';
 User::whereHas('receivedMessages', function ($q) use ($id) {
      $q->where('from', $id);
 });
```

This will give you all users who received a message from the user of that given id. If you want to get users who also sent messages to that user you can do:

```
 $userId = 'id of user to get conversations for';
 $collocutor = User::orWhereHas('receivedMessages', function ($q) use ($id) {
      $q->where('from', $id);
 })->orWhereHas('sentMessages', function ($q) use ($id) {
      $q->where('to', $id);
 });
```

Comment: I want both..  The user who I sent message to and those who sent to me